# hosting application on GAE & database on different server

Tags: google-app-engine, hosting, google-cloud-datastore, google-data-api

I want to host my java web application on GAE and my database on different server(GoDaddy). 
Google data store is free for only 6 months, So i would like to use database of different hosting(goDaddy). So is it possibe(in case of GAE)??

I am able to use database of my hosting(goDaddy) from my local system but when i upload my application to GAE than it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database provides a REST API for remote connections, then it should not be any problem. If you can access your database by using Sockets (i.e. java.net package) then this is not possible.

Also, Google App Engine provides free quota based on usage and not time. For more information please take a look at [App Engine Quotas](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas)

Comment: Thanks for answering... I am able to access GoDaddy database from my local system and i am not using REST API on server. I am just connecting like this ` <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://tvminvoicedb.db.9907479.hostedresource.com</property>` i have just provided address to my database on server and username and password of database. And i am not using sockets either.  
`